# class generics assignable issue

Tags: javascript, typescript

#### Error

> TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'C & Context'. Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Context'. '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Context', but 'Context' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'.

The Error is in `constructor` where I define the default value for context `context = {}` (in destructuring assignment)

#### What I am doing?

I'm trying to define generic type for Page with default value of empty object (also generic type has to be only object).

Then Page constructor has to accept custom object as context property in constructor argument. Default value of this context has to be an empty object but as a hints `type C` and `generic type Context` is used.

```
type C = {
  isProduction?: boolean;
  isTest?: boolean;
};

class Page<Context extends object = {}> {
  context: C & Context;

  readonly id: number;

  readonly name: string;

  constructor({ context = {}, id, name, }: { context?: C & Context; id: Page['id']; name: Page['name'] }) {
    this.context = context;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The error message is clear, `{}` is just not assignable to `Context` (actually, `extends {}` means nothing since every type satisfies this.

If you want `{}` to be a valid default value, probably you can change `Context` to `Partial<Context>`:

```
type C = {
  isProduction?: boolean;
  isTest?: boolean;
};

class Page<Context extends object = {}> {
  context: C & Partial<Context>;

  readonly id: number;

  readonly name: string;

  constructor({ context = {}, id, name, }: { context?: C & Partial<Context>; id: Page['id']; name: Page['name'] }) {
    this.context = context;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok It works but when I define `class Test extends Page<{ test: boolean }>` and then I did not apply `test` property to constructor -> argument -> context ... It will not throw an Error that I forgot to define test property

Comment: Heej answer me please